# Is there a way to put subcaption labels at the closest of a subfigure using subcaption and floatrow package

Tags: floats, captions, subcaption

I want to maximize the size of the pictures I use for my subfigures for that I want to put subfigure labels as close as possible  of my subfigures. I can't find a way to do that using subcaption and floatrow. What I have achieve so far is this code but I can't reduce the distance between (a) and the figure and same for (b). And push (a) to far left.

```
\documentclass[headsepline,DIV=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\floatsetup[subfigure]{heightadjust=object,capbesideposition=top}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=bf,textfont=normalfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
      \ffigbox[]
          {\begin{subfloatrow}
                 \fcapside[\FBwidth]{\caption{}\label{sfa}}{\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-a}}
                 \fcapside[\FBwidth]{\caption{}\label{sfb}}{\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-b}}
          \end{subfloatrow}
          }
      {\caption{
      \subref{sfa} and \subref{sfb} Recalcitrantes ut ut postulat tenus tenus et praefectum custodiri formidine
iusserim haec per contumacem novo quid ignorare haec custodiri quid novo maiestati quod ut praefectum strepit
praefectum quid ignorare quod quae strepit et strepit custodiri quid recalcitrantes inusitato iratus et iusserim
haec nimirum contumacem per formidine tumore contumacem ordo tumore. }\label{f:test}
      }
\end{figure}
Long text under my figure where I can reference any of the Fig~\ref{f:test} and subfigure~\subref{sfa} with some special names
kemmlkem mlake lka elmk .
\end{document}
```

[image]

At the moment I lost the fight against floatrow package but I am not done yet !

If you can help me, thank you very much !

Comment: Try add `\setlength{\labelsep}{1mm}` (or other distance size) after `begin{figure}`.

Comment: It is not working, it doesn't change anything. (I tried with different value to be sure)

Comment: You are right. I mess with similar answer where was used `subfloat ` package. There my suggestion works.

Answer (score 1):

Solution suggested in my comment works nice when is using `subfig` package instead `subcaption` and not used `\ffigbox[]`{...}:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[label font=bf, labelformat=simple]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont=bf,textfont=normalfont,labelformat=parens}

\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{height=0.2\textheight} % common settings for images heights
    \setlength{\labelsep}{1mm}  % <---
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image}\label{sfa}}
\hfil
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics{example-image}\label{sfb}}
    \caption{\protect\subref{sfa} and \protect\subref{sfb} Recalcitrantes ut ut postulat tenus tenus et praefectum custodiri formidine iusserim haec per contumacem novo quid ignorare haec custodiri quid novo maiestati quod ut praefectum strepit praefectum quid ignorare quod quae strepit et strepit custodiri quid recalcitrantes inusitato iratus et iusserim haec nimirum contumacem per formidine tumore contumacem ordo tumore.}
\label{f:test}
    \end{figure}
Long text under my figure where I can reference any of the Fig~\ref{f:test} and subfigure~\subref{sfa} with some special names \dots
\end{document}
```

Result is almost the same as with your MWE (except, that distance between caption labels and images is controlled by `\setlength{\labelsep}{1mm}`):

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you very much for your time. I did not mention it in my first post, but I managed to do it kind of the same thing with subcaption. But I wanted to avoid the \protect to be perfectionnist and that is the reason why I went from the package subfig to subcaption. Perhap's the cost is to high for the incovenience  ! Thank you very much for your time !